# R Shiny Module does not update input value on different tabs

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have an app which works with tabpanels that use many of the same inputs, and must be rendered using renderUI to respond to user data. I've noticed my modulated inputs give priority to the first menu they're rendered in and disregard changes made in different panels

The following is a simplified working example of the basic issue

```
library(shiny)
addexButtons <- function(id, label = "ROCParam") {
    ns <- NS(id)
    uiOutput(ns("roccondicionals"), label = label)
    
}

numbmod <- function(input, output, session, ndata) {
    output$roccondicionals <- renderUI({
        tagList(numericInput('numb', 'Choose Num', value = 0,))
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(navbarPage(
    'App',
    tabPanel(title = 'Menu 1',
             sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(addexButtons("counter1", "Adder")),
                 mainPanel(textOutput('sumtotal'))
             )),
    
    tabPanel(title = 'Menu 2',
             sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(addexButtons("counter2", "Multiplier"),),
                 mainPanel(textOutput('multiplytotal'))
             ))
    
))



server <- function(input, output) {
    callModule(numbmod, "counter1")
    callModule(numbmod, "counter2")
    
    output$sumtotal <-
        renderText(paste0('5 + ', input$numb, ' = ', input$numb + 5))
    
    output$multiplytotal <-
        renderText(paste0('5 x ', input$numb, ' = ', input$numb * 5))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you run this example you will see that, by changing to menu 2 the value retains the information modified in Menu 1 (which is intended) however if I choose to modify this same value in the same tab I can't and must return to Menu 1 to do so.

Is there a way to be able to modify the same rendered input on two different tabs where the last modification is the one retained?

Comment: I don't think you can define two numeric inputs with the same ID. That is the reason your input from menu 2 page is not being used. By giving it a different ID, you can write a logic to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @YBS has already mentioned you cannot define two inputs with the same id. I would use updateNumericInput to automatically update the inputs when of the inputs is changed (triggered).

```
library(shiny)
addexButtons <- function(id, label = "ROCParam") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("roccondicionals"), label = label)    
  }

numbmod <- function(input, output, session, ndata, n) {
  output$roccondicionals <- renderUI({
    numericInput(paste0("numb",n), 'Choose Num', value = 0)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(navbarPage(
  'App', id = "App",
  tabPanel(title = 'Menu1',
           tab_id = "tab1",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(addexButtons("counter1", "Adder")),
             mainPanel(textOutput('sumtotal'))
           )),
  
  tabPanel(title = 'Menu2',
           tab_id = "tab2",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(addexButtons("counter2", "Multiplier"),),
             mainPanel(textOutput('multiplytotal'))
           ))
  
))



server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$numb1, {
  updateNumericInput(session, "numb2", value = input$numb1)
    updateNavbarPage(session,"App", "Menu2")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$numb2, {
    updateNumericInput(session, "numb1", value = input$numb2)
    updateNavbarPage(session,"App", "Menu1")

  })
    
  callModule(numbmod, "counter1",n = 1)
  callModule(numbmod, "counter2",n = 2)
  output$sumtotal <-
    renderText(paste0('5 + ', input$numb1, ' = ', input$numb1 + 5))
  
  output$multiplytotal <-
    renderText(paste0('5 x ', input$numb2, ' = ', input$numb2 * 5))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```